# loop through date and print formated date

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    for(i=0;i<30;i++){

    }

    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var formatedDate = curr_date + '/' + curr_month + '/' + curr_year;
```

I'm stuck, how can I print out the next 30 days?

like 3/3/2015, 4/3/2015, 5/3/2015 and so on..

Comment: If you would just read your post you might see this is a clear case for rubber dug debugging http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDate();
for(i=0;i<30;i++){




     curr_day = curr_day+1;
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var newDate = new Date(curr_year,curr_month,curr_day)
    var formatedDate = newDate.getDate() + '/' + newDate.getMonth() + '/' + newDate.getFullYear();
   formatedDate;
   }
```

You need to increment the day variable

Comment: it will have 33/3/2015 haha

Comment: ahh, well in that case use this new code, it will increment the month when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
curr_month = curr_month + 1;
var curr_date = d.getDate();

for( i = curr_date; i <= 31; i++ ){
   var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
   var date = curr_date + '/' + curr_month + '/' + curr_year;
   curr_date++;
   console.log(date);
 }
```

Try this.It worked for me.

[demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/srg261/nnx1fes5/1/)

Comment: OP want to show next 30 days dates starting with current date, not current months remaining dates.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all that code below the loop inside the loop, then for each iteration add one day to the Date object. (add 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

```
var ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;


var d = new Date();

for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
  var formatedDate = curr_date + '/' + curr_month + '/' + curr_year;
  d = new Date(d.getMilliseconds() + ONE_DAY);
}
```

I would probably make slightly different style choices, but this is one way of doing it that pertains to the code you wrote.

Also, I don't have enough reputation to comment, but the other solution by pedrumj is very similar to mine, but keep in mind that it actually skips the first day (the new date should be assigned at the end of the loop)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sAvkA/1/)

Use this

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
for(i=0;i<30;i++){
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = curr_month + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var Printdate = curr_date + '/' + curr_month + '/' + curr_year;
console.log(Printdate);
 }
```

Comment: it will have 33/3/2015 :D

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the date field by 1 day on each loop as follows:

```
var d = new Date(1425356823380);

for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    var date = d.toLocaleDateString();
    // code
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w01n1ryc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop doesn't loop through anything. You should set your fixed variables first, then loop through your variable you wish to change.

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++){

}

var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var formatedDate = curr_date + '/' + curr_month + '/' + curr_year;
```

Like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var curr_day = d.getDay();
var formatedDate = curr_month + '/' + curr_day + '/' + curr_year;
for(i=0;i<30;i++){
    curr_day++;
    formattedDate = curr_month + '/' + curr_day + '/' + curr_year;
    console.log(formattedDate);
}
```

Mind, February only has 29 days at most.

See the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) for more information. You may just want to use a library that can handle all the strange edge cases that happen with dates, such as [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<30;i++){    
    var start = new Date();
    var next = new Date();
    next.setDate(start.getDate() + i);
    var date_str=next.getDay()+"/"+next.getMonth()+"/"+next.getFullYear()
    console.log(next);
}
```

You can format start, next date as per your need.